# Why do so many players like to start at Tilted Towers?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Why do so many players drop at Tilted Towers in Battle Royal mode? Why not start somewhere else so you have to fight less?

Comment: I don't see this as opinion based. The question may not have been phrased perfectly, but it's a legitimate strategy question.

Comment: Its exactly that, because they want to fight more. Its an instant brawl where you are more or less guaranteed a kill.. or death lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- It has the most chests-per-square in all of Fortnite, with 40 chests in a POI* ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/7rvd37/all_40_chest_locations_in_tilted_towers/]%22here%22)). POI's are roughly 3/4mp²**
- It is nearest to the centre of the map, and is always partially, fully or near to the storm. Worst case scenario, you may have to cross the river to enter the circle, which is only about 100m away.
- The more people go there, the more people start to go there. People may want to land at Tilted, not for the loot, but for a short, intense game, or for completion of quests which may involve elimination of enemies with specific weapons.
- It's a challenge. People go to Tilted because it's fun!

*Point Of Interest - a named location on the map

**MP is short for Map Piece. The map uses an 8 by 8 grid labelled down the side and top. One MP is one of these squares, or 250m² in Metric terms. This gives us a chest density of approximately 1 chest in 4m², not counting height. A player can loot 2 chests in a short 30 second interval.

Answer (score 7):

Though there is no set in stone ruleset regarding dropping in tilted towers, the general accepted reason(s) is/are:

1. A lot of loot, if you manage to survive and come out on top you almost certainly have a wide and/or good variaty of weapons at your disposal.
2. The Chance to instantly  go into combat. Though it is in general more likely you will die early it is also a good place to hone skill as you will instantly be required to fight.